# RegEx to clean up and combine email campaigns in Google Data Studio

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I'm pretty new to RegEx and am trying to create an expression to clean up some inconsistent email campaign naming so that I can report on them nicely in Google Data Studio.

I have tried to self-assess by Googling and haven't had any luck.

I'm creating a quarterly report, so I want to report on our last three monthly enewsletters. For September, for example, I have these three Campaign name iterations:

```
0fbc60f462-ENEWS_2019_SEPTEMBER
023a182219-ENEWS_2019_SEPTEMBER
41afe1cac5-ENEWS_2019_SEPTEMBER
```

They all have different `Pageviews`, `Sessions`, etc. Ideally, for July, August and September like to:

1. Remove the numbers in front and;
2. Combine them together

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this in Data Studio with a calculated field using a Case Statement such as:

```
CASE
    WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Campaign, "ENEWS_2019_SEPTEMBER$") THEN "ENEWS_2019_SEPTEMBER"
END
```

Further information on CASE statements:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en

Comment: To clarify for my own understanding, Is it just the combined email campaigns you want shown in a single table, or other campaigns as well as the combined Sept email campaigns all in the same single table?